# Accessing localhost in Curl PHP Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, curl, docker-compose, postman

I know there are a million articles on this on Stack and I feel like I went through all of them but I still can't get my Curl call to work. I am pretty sure this is an issue with using `localhost` within the same docker container.

I am setting up a local WordPress/DB/PHPMyAdmin site

When I use POSTMAN on my local machine my Curl call works fine which makes sense since I am calling localhost outside of the container, but if I run the Curl/PHP within the container in PHP the response is blank and the error I get is `Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`

I was messing with `CURLOPT_PROXY` in Curl to see if I change to the IP of the container that would work, but it doesn't. Also tried changing from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in the URL with no luck.

The Curl code I just copied from POSTMAN

I use `docker-compose up -d` to start the containers.

what am I not seeing?

**PHP**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/users?context=edit',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
//   CURLOPT_PROXY => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . ':' .  $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'],
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'X-WP-Nonce: 636d66e8a1',
    'Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_70490311fe7c84acda8886406a6d884b=cbielich%7C1645833231%7CzzVjOsgeU2kUHn8dpzbcn3wq9oXsBhLN486RMlQdJxY%7C12b4367f5b1f76a00741ec9cd0e77cf38657accd20ab6cbc5af257084d13566c',
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $err = curl_error($curl);
```

**YAML**

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: If you're making that call from inside the `wordpress` container, the `ports:` remapping won't have taken effect, and from the point of view of this `localhost`, there's a server listening on port 80 and not 8000.  I might make that URL configurable via an environment variable or other setting.